# Number multiplied by constant results in a negative number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, operator-precedence

I'm trying to calculate the date for a corresponding week-of-year one year ago. It seems to be working now but one thing botters me that initially lead to a couple of errors that I fixed by experimenting with various methods.

The issue is that when I don't use `to_number` with `&weekOfYearNow - &weekOfYearThen` and use this result to calculate the `lastYearFixed` then the result will be `-311` instead of `7`. Why is this so? Aren't that two variables (`weekOfYearNow` & `weekOfYearThen`) already numbers?

```sql
define today = to_date('30/12/20', 'dd/mm/yy');
define lastYear = add_months(&today, -12);

select &today as "Today" from sys.dual;
select &lastYear as "LastYear" from sys.dual;

define weekOfYearNow = to_number(to_char(&today, 'ww'));
define weekOfYearThen = to_number(to_char(&lastYear, 'ww'));
define weekOfYearOffset = to_number(&weekOfYearNow - &weekOfYearThen); -- <-- must use to_number - but why?

define lastYearFixed = &lastYear + (&weekOfYearOffset * 7); -- <-- this equals -311 if I don't call to_number above

define monday = add_months(sysdate - 7 - to_char(sysdate, 'd') + 2, -12);
define sunday = add_months(sysdate - 7 + to_char(sysdate, 'd'), -12);

select &weekOfYearNow as "WeekOfYearNow" from sys.dual;
select &weekOfYearThen as "WeekOfYearThen" from sys.dual;
select &weekOfYearOffset as "WeekOfYearOffset" from sys.dual;
select &lastYearFixed as "LastYearFixed" from sys.dual;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need (and shouldn't use) `to_number()`; but you do need to enclose the first expression in parentheses, either as:

```
define weekOfYearOffset = (&weekOfYearNow - &weekOfYearThen);
define lastYearFixed = &lastYear + (&weekOfYearOffset * 7);
```

or

```
define weekOfYearOffset = &weekOfYearNow - &weekOfYearThen;
define lastYearFixed = &lastYear + ((&weekOfYearOffset) * 7);
```

Without either of those, when the substitution is expanded you effectively get:

```
define lastYearFixed = &lastYear + (&weekOfYearNow - &weekOfYearThen * 7);
```

(It actually has all those terms expanded to show the nested `to_date()` and `to_number()` etc. calls, but for brevity this gives the idea; the point is they are not yet numbers, and no conversions or calculations have been done yet. You can `set verify on` to see the full glory/horror.)

The [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/About-SQL-Operators.html#GUID-FEF44762-F45C-41D9-B380-F6A61AD25338) has `*` as a higher precedence than (binary) `-`, which means that is equivalent to:

```
define lastYearFixed = &lastYear + (&weekOfYearNow - (&weekOfYearThen * 7));
```

So you're adding `weekOfYearNow` and subtracting 7 times `weekOfYearThen`; rather than adding 7 times the difference between them.

In numbers:

```
select 53 - 52 * 7 as a,
       53 - (52 * 7) as b,
       (53 - 52) * 7 as c
from dual;

    A     B     C
----- ----- -----
 -311  -311     7
```

When you use `to_number()` you are overring the default precedence, but with an unnecessary implicit conversion to a string and explicit conversion back to a number. Just the parentheses are enough to override the default behaviour.

Comment: I would never have thought that these expressions aren't resolved immediately but just substituted as a whole. This totaly makes sense now! And is pretty scarry at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the main difference with Gary's PL/SQL version - there they are evaluated as they are assigned, but that isn't how substitution variables work. (You still need to be careful with [precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-65EAAB52-8E2C-45E1-B004-CA00A942FF0C), of course!) If you do `set verify on` in your session then you can see the old/new queries before and after substitution. They're actually more expanded than I showed, but you can still see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say I bet it's a SQL/Plus thing (and Alex proved that, thanks Alex) as when I converted it to a PL/SQL anonymous block and ran it in Toad it worked as expected. I was not going to post this as it is not really an answer, but then it's kind of interesting to compare the languages and note gotcha's that could bite you that one should keep in mind so I'll leave it for the sake of learning.

```
SET serveroutput ON

DECLARE
  today DATE;
  lastyear DATE;
  weekOfYearNow NUMBER;
  weekOfYearThen NUMBER;
  weekOfYearOffset NUMBER;
  lastYearFixed DATE;
  monday DATE;
  sunday DATE;
BEGIN
 today := TO_DATE('30/12/20', 'dd/mm/yy');
 lastYear := ADD_MONTHS(today, -12);

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Today: ' || today);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LastYear: ' || lastYear);

 weekOfYearNow    := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(today, 'ww'));
 weekOfYearThen   := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(lastYear, 'ww'));
 weekOfYearOffset := weekOfYearNow - weekOfYearThen; -- <-- must use to_number - but why?

 lastYearFixed := lastYear + (weekOfYearOffset * 7); -- <-- this equals -311 if I don't call to_number above

 monday := ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE - 7 - TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'd') + 2, -12);
 sunday := ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE - 7 + TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'd'), -12);

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WeekOfYearNow: ' || WeekOfYearNow);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WeekOfYearThen: ' || WeekOfYearThen);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('WeekOfYearOffset: ' || WeekOfYearOffset);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LastYearFixed: ' || LastYearFixed);

END;

Today: 30-DEC-20
LastYear: 30-DEC-19
WeekOfYearNow: 53
WeekOfYearThen: 52
WeekOfYearOffset: 1
LastYearFixed: 06-JAN-20
```